# youtube - gdata api - specific columns?

Tags: youtube-api, gdata-api

I am using gdata api to retrieve information about specific youtube videos using something like this below:

```
        Uri  videoEntryUrl = new Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ADos_xW4_J0?format=5");
        Video video = request.Retrieve<Video>(videoEntryUrl);
```

However, I wonder if there is a way to specify that I am only interested in certain fields of the video rather than getting the complete video feed. For example, say I am only interested in commentcount AND viewcount of the video. However, the code above will return the entire Video class which seems I may be consuming more bandwidth than needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for something like this?

```
http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ADos_xW4_J0?format=5&fields=yt:statistics,gd:comments&alt=json
```

Comment: You can also use "prettyprint=true" query parameter.